# is it possible to set a timer for a boolean statement from true to false and false to true at a particular time every day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timer

I currently have a database working with a column that has boolean statements. The issue I'm encountering is that I'm trying to add a functionality where at a particular time frame the value turns (true) or (false). For example from 8:00 am to 11:30 am I want the statement to be (True) and from 11:31 am - 7:59 am to be (false). The intention is for me to not need to go to the database and manually do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome the community! Can you please post examples of what you have tried and outlined what research you have done, so the community will be better able to assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may want to schedule a job to run on the database that executes some sort of stored procedure/function that updates those column values to true/false

Comment: that is correct, is it a matter of functionality within PGADMIN or is it code that needs to be added to my existing code to trigger booleans from true to false and vice versa depending on time and day?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view:

```
create view v_times as
    select (current_time < '11:30:00' and current_time >= '08:00:00') as is_breakfast_time
```

Similar logic could be put into a user-defined function.